# python name of description in angle bracket

Tags: python

In the python interpreter, one could do:

```
import smtplib
```

then, if one were to type:

```
smtplib.LMTP()
```

one would get something like:

```
<class smtplib.LMTP at 0xsomeaddress>
```

Question: what is the generic name for the above?
Is it an "object"?

I understand that one could instantiate like so:

```
a = smtplib.LMTP()
```

and `a` would be called an "instance" of `smtplib.LMTP()`

but what is `<....>` as in my example above?

Citation needed, please (preferably from docs.python.org)

Comment: That is the default `repr`esentation, i.e. what is shown for a `Class` if `Class.__repr__` isn't defined. See https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both are objects.

In both cases, you are instantiating the LMTP class. The difference is that in the latter case, you save away a reference to it (a). When you assign the LMTP instance to a, the object information <...> is simply just not printed.

To illustrate:

```
>>> import smtplib
>>> smtplib.LMTP()
<smtplib.LMTP instance at 0x10e581ab8>
>>> a = smtplib.LMTP()
>>> a
<smtplib.LMTP instance at 0x10e5815a8>
```

In the above case, the first instance of LMTP does not have a reference and will be garbage collected. The second instance is referenced by a and will be garbage collected when it leaves the scope. The first part of <...> tell you from which class the object is instantiated from, the second part tell you where in memory.